# How to make inherited fields of non-audited base entity being audited for audited child entity in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, audit

I have a base entity not intended to be audited:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Date createdAt;
```

and there is a subclass like:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditTable(schema = "audit", value = "bank")
@Table(name = "bank")
public class Bank extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

so as the final result I get only `name` column falls into the `audit.bank` audit table, while `created_at` isn't. How I can make it being auditable, not breaking the inheritance of entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@AuditOverride(forClass = BaseEntity.class, isAudited = true)
```

helped me